# Swagger Implementaion issue in WSo2 API Manager

Tags: wso2

WSO2 Api Manager is working fine in all aspects but getting an issue in the API Console Module while using Store.

While designing an API, we have selected only http transport and published. In API Console, while trying the swagger, we are getting http calls with 9443 not with 8280 which is the actual port where the production url is launched.

Trying out the production url with 8280 port works fine with Curl and External REst Client.

Please help to resolve this issue as the end user cannot try it out before subscribing if this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is identified as a bug in the API Manager product. So I have created a JIRA[1] for the issue and please keep track the issue for the details.

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-5254